# Can you get a Rails partial's name from within the partial?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, partial-views

Is there a variable that contains a partial's name accessible from within the partial?

```
render partial: 'foo'
```

In `_foo.haml`:

```
.name
  = partial_name # would output "foo"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`__FILE__` will give you the file name

```
<% __FILE__.split("/").last.sub(/^_/, "") %>
```

Comment: Thanks, I knew about the `__FILE__` variable. I was hoping there was something local like the `partial_counter`.

Answer (score 1):

In your partial:

```
    <%= partial_class(__FILE__) %>
```

In application_helper:

```
    def partial_class(partial)
        partial.split(".").first.split("/").last.sub(/^_/, "")
    end
```

Result: partial is '_customer-existing.html.erb', output is 'customer-existing'. I use this constantly for class names on a wrapper div inside the partial, so that I can use the same name in jquery to show/hide the partial.

Example:

```
<div class='<%= partial_class(__FILE__) %>'>
  stuff here that will be show/hideable by partial name.
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a helper in application_helper for this and use rubys introspection abilities
so you dont have to explicitly pass **FILE**
like in Mikes answer.

```
def foo                                                                                                                 
  caller_locations(1, 1).first.path                                                                                     
end
```